# Telepathic alien chicken - dystopian sci fi

Tags: story-identification, books

I've read a book about a guy in a post-apocalyptic world who had a chicken that later on showed herself to be some kind of an alien. Pretty weird stuff but it makes sense in the book.

I remember the cover, of course there was a chicken/hen on it but not the title. It was a very interesting sci fi novel, only read it once probably more then 10 years ago.  It would be great to find it again. I believe it was written by a British or American author.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Future Eden: A Brief History of Next Time*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/482389.Future_Eden) by Colin Thompson.

[image: cover of Future Eden showing Ethel the alien telepathic chicken]

> In a hilarious and scathing sci-fi adventure, it is the year 2287 and the human race is doomed until Jay and an all-powerful chicken named Ethel set off to save the world. They encounter goldfish-oracles, evil roosters, giant potatoes, blind piano tuners, Merlin, and magic spells in their heroic quest.

Found with a search for `novel alien chicken telepath`

Comment: Many thanks mate! This is the book I was looking for...I need to read it again since it became a bit relevant, lol.